# max CSS function with percentage argument not working on th element

Tags: html, css

I want to make the width of table columns responsive to the width of table while keeping the minimum width.
To do so, I applied `min-width: max(500px, 33.3%)` to `th` element but all the column seems to have neither of 500px nor 33.3% width.
Where am I doing wrong?

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

th {
  min-width: max(500px, 33.3%);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

https://codepen.io/hitochan777/pen/wvzgELE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to separate the two values ​​with

`min-width: max(500px); width: 33.3%;`

Comment: the max(500px) does nothing here, as max takes the maximum out of a list of arguments. The maximum out of a list with the single element 500px is 500px obviously

Answer (score 0):

Simple just do width at 33.3%. It will scale with the browser window.

```
    th {width: 33.3%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

th {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    max-width: 33.3%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  th {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Title of the document</title>

    </head>

    <body>

   
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;name&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;age&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th>address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

try this!